# Why such a bad performance for Moses using Europarl?

Tags: corpus, machine-translation, moses, bleu

I have started playing around with Moses and tried to make what I believe would be a fairly standard baseline system. I have basically followed [the steps described on the website](http://www.statmt.org/moses/?n=Moses.Baseline), but instead of using `news-commentary` I have used [Europarl](http://www.statmt.org/europarl/) v7 for training, with the WMT 2006 development set and the original Europarl common test. My idea was to do something similar to [Le Nagard & Koehn (2010),](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1868887) who obtained a BLEU score of .68 in their baseline English-to-French system.

To summarise, my workflow was more or less this:

1. `tokenizer.perl` on everything
2. `lowercase.perl` (instead of `truecase`)
3. `clean-corpus-n.perl`
4. Train IRSTLM model using only French data from Europarl v7
5. `train-model.perl` exactly as described
6. `mert-moses.pl` using WMT 2006 dev
7. Testing and measuring performances as described

And the resulting BLEU score is .26... This leads me to two questions:

- Is this a typical BLEU score for this kind of baseline system? I realise Europarl is a pretty small corpus to train a monolingual language model on, even though this is how they do things on the Moses website.
- Are there any typical pitfalls for someone just starting with SMT and/or Moses I may have fallen in? Or do researchers like Le Nagard & Koehn build their baseline systems in a way different from what is described on the Moses website, for instance using some larger, undisclosed corpus to train the language model?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to put things straight first: the .68 you are referring to has nothing to do with BLEU.

> My idea was to do something similar to Le Nagard & Koehn (2010), who obtained a BLEU score of .68 in their baseline English-to-French system.

The article you refer to only states that 68% of the pronouns (using co-reference resolution) was translated correctly. It nowhere mentions that a .68 BLEU score was obtained. As a matter of fact, no scores were given, probably because the qualitative improvement the paper proposes cannot be measured with statistical significance (which happens a lot if you only improve on a small number of words). For this reason, the paper uses a manual evaluation of the pronouns only:

> A better evaluation metric is the number of correctly
>   translated pronouns. This requires manual
>   inspection of the translation results.

This is where the .68 comes into play.

Now to answer your questions with respect to the .26 you got:

> Is this a typical BLEU score for this kind of baseline system? I realise Europarl is a pretty small corpus to train a monolingual language model on, even though this is how they do things on the Moses website.

Yes it is. You can find the performance of WMT language pairs here http://matrix.statmt.org/

> Are there any typical pitfalls for someone just starting with SMT and/or Moses I may have fallen in? Or do researchers like Le Nagard & Koehn build their baseline systems in a way different from what is described on the Moses website, for instance using some larger, undisclosed corpus to train the language model?

I assume that you trained your system correctly. With respect to the "undisclosed corpus" question: members of the academic community normally state for each experiment which data sets were used for training testing and tuning, at least in peer-reviewed publications. The only exception is the WMT task (see for example http://www.statmt.org/wmt14/translation-task.html) where privately owned corpora may be used if the system participates in the unconstrained track. But even then, people will mention that they used additional data.

Comment: Damn it, you're totally right w.r.t. Le Nagard & Koehn. I read it too quickly, and got confused by the fact that they mention BLEU but never actually give any numbers.